# How to unpunctuate, lowercase, de-space and hyphenate a string with regex?

Tags: regex, string

If I have a string like this

```
Newsflash: The Big(!) Brown Dog's Brother (T.J.) Ate The Small Blue Egg
```

how would I convert that into the following using regex:

```
newsflash-the-big-brown-dogs-brother-tj-ate-the-small-blue-egg
```

In other words, punctuation is discarded and spaces are replaced with hyphens.

Comment: In what language? Btw, you can't (reasonably) lower- or upper-case a string using regex.

Comment: Regular expressions can’t do string operations; they can only describe strings.

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like you want to create a "URL plug" -- a URL-friendly version of an article's title, for example.  That means you'll want to make sure you remove all possible non-URL-friendly characters, not just a few.  You might do it this way (in order):

**Remove all non-letter non-number non-space characters by:**
Replacing regex `[^A-Za-z0-9 ]` with the empty string `""`.

**Replace all spaces with a dash by:**
Replacing regex `\s+` with the string `"-"`.

**Lower-case the string by:**
Java `s = s.toLowerCase();`
JavaScript `s = s.toLowerCase();`
C#  `s = s.ToLowerCase();`
Perl  `$s = lc($s);`
Python `s = s.lower()`
PHP `$s = strtolower($s);`
Ruby `s = s.downcase`

Comment: `[^A-z0-9 ]` is simpler than `[^A-Za-z0-9 ] `. Also I don't know much about regex but why doesn't it match `A-z0-9 `? Why is it doing the inverse? I don't get it. Nevermind, I see `^` represents a negated set.

Answer (score 1):

Replace the regex `[\s-]+` with `"-"`, then replace `[^\w-]` with `""`.

Then, call `ToLowerCase` or equivalent.

In Javascript:

```
var s = "Newsflash: The Big(!) Brown Dog's Brother (T.J.) Ate The Small Blue Egg";
alert(s.replace(/[\s+-]/g, '-').replace(/[^\w-]/g, '').toLowerCase());
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `/\W+/` with '-', that will replace all non-word characters with a dash.

Then, collapse dashes by replacing `/-+/` with '-'.

Then, lowercase the string - pure regex solutions cannot do that. You didn't say which language you are using, so I cannot give you an example, but your language might have String.toLowercase() or a `tr///` call (`tr/A-Z/a-z/`, for example, in Perl).